# Smarty cdn output filter for images

Tags: php, image, url, smarty

Output filter for smarty which replaces image URL inside smarty templates with your cdn url

e.g. an image like:

```
<img src="/images/image.gif"/>

<img src="http://cdn.yoursite.com/images/image.gif"/>
```

Comment: Please try to further explain your problem and what your process is for getting this file on your web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's  like that

```
<?php  function smarty_outputfilter_cdn($tpl_source, &$smarty)  {      if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == 80) {          $tpl_source = preg_replace('/("|\')((\.\/|\/)[A-z0-9_\-\/@\.]+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png))("|\')/i', "\"http://cdn.yoursite.com\\2\"", $tpl_source);      }            return $tpl_source;  }  ?>
```